My regex in python doesn't match using re.search()
I'm trying to extract the substring $200 from this text:
Autorización 28 MAY 2024, 20:34 (hora de CDMX)


$200.oo Monto

Concept
I'm using the next method in a for:
monto = re.search('^[$][0-9]+', line in the text)
But it doesn't match.

You have a ^ in your regexp, which anchors it to the start of the string. From the re manual:

^
(Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.

That's naturally no good if you want to find something in the middle of a string (unless you do actually want to find matches at new lines in the string, then set the flags=re.MULTILINE option, as shown above).
Try
re.search(r'[$][0-9]+', ...)

instead (so no anchoring).
